# Missing data in test data for Azure MachineforMachine Learning

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am new to Azure Machine Learning. I have created a training experiment where training data has some missing values. The logic for handling missing data and few other transformations is in Python code which works on this data.

Now I want the same for test data. I have deployed the experiment as web service. So, the schema is produced for input and output data (all are Numeric fields).

Two questions:
1. It asks me to define the label for test data as well, otherwise it gives inconsistent number of columns error since label column is missing in the test data
2. I have some missing data in test data, which ideally Python script in the experiment should take care. But it gives me the following error because of schema.

```
The request failed with status code: 400
Content-Length: 323
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 11:44:49 GMT
Connection: close

{u'error': {u'message': u'Invalid argument provided.', u'code': 'BadArgument', u'details': [{u'message': u'Parsing of input vector failed.  Verify the input vector has the correct number of columns and data types.  Additional details: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32..', u'code': u'InputParseError', u'target': u'input1'}]}}
```

Comment: Could you supply some testing data sample and some code  for analysing the issue?

Comment: Regarding your second question, have you tried the clean missing data module instead of your R code? Might be easier/simpler if you cant get your code working.

Answer (score 1):

@Sagar,

```
u'message': u'Parsing of input vector failed.  Verify the input vector has the correct number of columns and data types.  

Additional details: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32..', u'code': u'InputParseError',
```

Form the error message, I suggest you should make sure your column Number and data type must match to your input data. For example,
if you have the decimal number, please use the `Double` data type instead of `Integer`.
Also, you can post your column and data type defined, even your testing data for further steps.